# Property in Django Model

Tags: python, django, properties

I want to improve my view in django using property in Models.
commented code worked fine but when I add property in Model I got blank space in template

views.py:

```
        cal_day = {}
        cal_day['day'] = day
        cal_day['day_event'] = False
        cal_day['sports'] = []
        for event in event_list:
            if day >= event.reservation_date.date() and day <= event.reservation_date.date():
                cal_day['day_event'] = True
                hours_week.append(event.reservation_date.time())
                # a = Reservation.objects.get(id=event.id)                    
                # d = dict()
                # d['id'] = a.id
                # d['sport'] = a.sport
                # d['trainer'] = a.trainer
                # d['reservation_date'] = a.reservation_date
                # d['free_space'] = (a.sport.capacity - a.users.count())
                # d['duration'] = a.sport.duration
                # d['time'] = a.reservation_date.time()
                # cal_day['sports'].append(d)
                print(Reservation.reservation_info)
                cal_day['sports'].append(Reservation.reservation_info)
```

models.py

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    sport = models.ForeignKey('Sport')
    trainer = models.ForeignKey('MyUser' ,related_name='Trainer')
    users = models.ManyToManyField('MyUser', blank = True)
    reservation_date = models.DateTimeField(null = True, blank = True)


    @property
    def reservation_info(self):

        d = dict()
        d['id'] = self.id 
        d['sport'] = self.sport
        d['trainer'] = self.trainer
        d['reservation_date'] = self.reservation_date
        d['free_space'] = (self.sport.capacity - self.users.count())
        d['duration'] = self.sport.duration
        d['time'] = self.reservation_date.time()
        return d

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} , {}'.format(self.sport, self.reservation_date)
```

in terminal  get printed  objects:

If someone can help to understand  what I am doing wrong  and how i can improve it to fork fine  i will by grateful  :)

Comment: A roblem, eh? Sounds erious.

Comment: Nice hack, as the word "problem" is not allowed on title

Comment: You dont seem to print the instance-property but the class one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the property with the class. The commented code worked because you were using an instance:

```
a = Reservation.objects.get(id=event.id)
d = dict()
# ...
d['reservation_date'] = a.reservation_date  # this works!
```